# correct usage of limit_choices_to in django models

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-2.2

Please help me to limit model team choices based on the company. Right now I put test value "1" and it's working correctly (function _limit_function). But how to limit it dynamically based on the selected company?

```
class CustomCompany(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,
            default="None",
            unique=True
            )

class CustomTeam(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(
            max_length=30,
            default="None"
            )

    company = models.ForeignKey(
            CustomCompany,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            )


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    def _limit_function():
        return {"company__id":1}


    phone = models.CharField(
            max_length=20,
            blank=True
            )

    company = models.ForeignKey(
            CustomCompany,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            default=1
            )

    team = models.ForeignKey(
            CustomTeam,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            default=1,
            limit_choices_to = _limit_function()
            )
```

So, I need to limit variants of team values, based on the selected company. Please help to understand how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something you cannot do in models.py
The form is rendered in the client browser, which has no access to your models.py file during data entry, unless you click submit multiple times while entering the data.
The best way is, to write a little Java-Script function with a event listener (something like: teamfield.addEventListener("keydown...,on key code==113)) which monitors the form field and changes the choices object based on the selected company.